# How to convert MAC address of any router to WPS pin using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, interop, wifi, wlanapi, wps

I need to make a program that converts router's MAC Address to Wifi Protected Setup PIN , also I need to connect to any WiFi network using Wifi Protected Setup PIN

I am using VB.NET Language.

Comment: The WPS PIN is auto-generated and can be regenerated on most routers. It is not related to the router's MAC address in any way.

Comment: Yeah , i know . but There is a program Called Dumpper which makes calculations on MAC Address and convert it to wps pin , it may be correct.

Comment: Have you tried that application yourself and can verify that it works? How can you be certain that it's not just brute-forcing the PIN?

Comment: As I said most routers can regenerate the PIN, so unless the router uses some cryptographically insecure method of generating it then it should be impossible to calculate from the outside without brute-forcing.

Comment: @VisualVincent , try this program https://sourceforge.net/projects/dumpper/    and reply to me , this program calculates the WPS PIN from MAC Address , Connects to router using WPS PIN Method

Comment: Just by reading the description of it I already see that it operates on security flaws. The purpose of Dumpper is to detect those flaws in the router. The WPS protocol is already known to have some really bad flaws that makes it easy to crack, so there's no conventional "calculation" done by the program. Dumpper simply attacks the router.

Comment: The author of Dumpper doesn't appear to share his source code though, so finding out _how_ it is done is going to be hard.

Comment: According to [**this**](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/85612/how-does-dumpper-program-get-default-wps-without-bruteforcing-them) the WPS PIN actually is MAC based in some cases, thus it uses a really bad implementation. But it is apparently only possible to calculate the _**default**_ PIN, not if you've changed it.

Comment: @VisualVincent , you are right , thus i need to know the VB.NET code to get Default PIN , i know that dumpper 90% fails , but the program worked on many routers , i have tried it .

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the Free Managed `Wifi API` from `CodePlex` at the link below.

> It does not say if it supports both XP and newer OS`s from Vista up
>   but, you can try it out.

[Managed Wifi API](https://managedwifi.codeplex.com/releases/view/7718)

Comment: I know this website , but there are two problems :- 1-The used language is C#  2-It doesn't contain a tutorial for converting MAC address to WPS Pin